# Cleaner way of dividing a list of tuples into multiple lists

Tags: python, numpy

The title is self explanatory, is there a one line expression to do so ?

Reproducible example:

```
Data = [(21,1,2000), (30,0,1991), (27,0,1994)]

age = [el[0] for el in Data]
sex = [el[1] for el in Data]
birth = [el[2] for el in Data]

print(age, sex, birth)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
age, sex, birth = zip(*Data)  # tuple

# OR

age, sex, birth = map(list, zip(*Data))  # list
```

```
>>> age
[21, 30, 27]

>>> sex
[1, 0, 0]

>> birth
[2000, 1991, 1994]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get'em as lists by chance ? Either way, your line was a beauty

Comment: Yes you can:  `map(list, zip(*Data))`

Answer (score 4):

A little modification to @Corralien solution, to get the result in `list` not in `tuple`, use `map`, `zip` together to get the result

```
Data = [(21,1,2000), (30,0,1991), (27,0,1994)]
age, sex, birth = map(list, zip(*Data))
print(age, sex, birth, sep ='\n')
```

output

```
[21, 30, 27] # age
[1, 0, 0] # sex
[2000, 1991, 1994] # birth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can do this by combining zip() with map() :

Data = [(21,1,2000), (30,0,1991), (27,0,1994)]
result = list(map(list, zip(*Data)))
print(result) 
# [[21, 30, 27], [1, 0, 0], [2000, 1991, 1994]]
```